# Checar se programa foi compilado para 32 ou 64 bits

Tags: pascal

Boa tarde, estou configurando meu fpc aqui para cross-compilation e gostaria de ter certeza de que esteja funcionando corretamente, quero fazer um programa teste e compilar em cada plataforma, logo depois checando se cada executável foi compilado para a plataforma correta.

No C++ eu usava o resultado de `sizeof(void*)` (conforme os comentários [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853312/sizeof-void-pointer)) como base, mas não sei se existe um equivalente preciso no Pascal.

Então, qual é a melhor forma programaticamente de se detectar sob qual tipo de CPU o executavel está sendo executado (não qual o tipo do OS)?

Comment: No processo de compilação, o tamanho da palavra já é definido. Não tem como o programa de adaptar depois de ter sido compilado.

Comment: Segundo [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19924881/4438007), Pascal não tem tipos dependentes da arquitetura da máquina

Comment: Bom, o exemplo acima do sizeof eu usei como exemplo, não precisaria ser desse jeito. Então não há mesmo nenhum modo de se detectar se o programa é 32 ou 64 no pascal?

Comment: Pelo que estou interpretando, não. É preocupação sua garantir que fez o build do x86 no lugar certo, assim como o do x86_64. Talvez inclusive o seu build do Pascal rode em uma VM... mas estou a estudar isso melhor ainda

Comment: Ok então, obrigado

Comment: `SizeOf(pointer)`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18771293/4438007